# multiplicity of non-zero real root of the derivative

Tags: polynomials

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be an even polynomial. Let $x$ be a non-zero real root of the $f'$, i.e. $f'(x)=0$. Is it possible that $x$ has multiplicity greater than 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure. Consider
$$
f(t)=t^6-3t^4+3t^2
$$
Then
$$
f'(t)=6t(t-1)^2(t+1)^2
$$

Comment: Not correct. $f'(t)=6t (t^2+1)(t^2-1)$.

Comment: @Dony Thanks, fixed. A too fast integration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example  $f (t)=(t-6)^{4710}$ , $x=6$

Comment: oops.  I changed the degree to 4710

Comment: This f is NOT even

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take $f(x)=x^4(x-1)^4(x+1)^4$. Then $\pm1$ are critical points of multiplicity $3$.

Comment: Good example! Following your idea, I come up with a simpler one: $f(t)=(t^2-1)^3$